# Profile Manager MDM

Tags: ios, mdm

Running into problems with the Profile Manager MDM, it isn't supervising iOS devices when supervised is selected leaving applications and settings open. Trying to apply this to iPad 2s and iPad 4s that are running iOS 7.1.2. Any ideas/suggestions as to why this is happening and possible solutions for this problem?

Another issue is that the remote management profile is able to be removed by the user which will allow the user to do whatever they want on the device. This is sporadic among the devices that were enrolled within the MDM's control. Any ideas as to how to lock this down?